# Undo drag&drop operation

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I use android's drag&drop functionallity to move some imageviews into another imageview. This allows to make a selection depending on what imageview I dropped into the destiny imageview.

But now I have to consider that the user could make a mistake when selecting, and need to have some kind of reset button, which would return these imageview's to their original place and cancel the drag&drop.

I've been reading the android doc and looking for this on google but I haven't found nothing, so I don't know if even a functionality like this exists.

I'll post my code for if someone could have and idea on how to get it, but it just is the standard code for this functionallity.

First a listener for the Imageviews that when long click it starts the drag operation:

```
private final class MyLongTouchListener implements OnLongClickListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);
        v.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, v, 0);
        v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then the Listener for the drop operation in the destiny imageview:

```
class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
                //...
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                //...
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
                //...
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                //...
                break;
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
                //...
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A still don't know if that functionality exists, but I've found a way to get a similar result.

When you want to do the reset, just do `finish()` and then launch an `intent` to restart the activity.

This would leave the things as at the begining, but maybe in some cases won't be useful. For me works.

Comment: Finishing the activity doesn't help. it will reset the drag but it's not the right way. the user doesn't want to kill the activity and start a new one